# Bokeh Jitter not working

Tags: bokeh, jitter

I'm trying to add jitter to a plot so that duplicate values don't overlap each other and the code runs fine but the display HTML file gives me an error.

The code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Jitter

x = [1,2,3,4,5,3,3,3]
y = [1,2,2,4,5,2,3,3]

data = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y))

output_file("iris.html")

f=figure()

f.plot_width = 800
f.plot_height = 800
f.sizing_mode="stretch_both"

f.circle(x={'value': "x", 'transform': Jitter(width=0.4)}, y="y", source=data)

show(f)
```

The error I get when I open the HTML file is:

```
Bokeh Error
Number property 'x' given invalid value: "x"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a great error message, but the problem is you're trying to transform the value "x" and not the field "x" of your data source. It should work it:

```
f.circle(x={'field': "x", 'transform': Jitter(width=0.4)}, y="y", source=data)
```